# Python Calculating PSD and CSD of ONE Array

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectral-density, mlab

I got some problem in my signal analysis. I load an array in my script (x) with the shape of x(68, 815). 68 represent the number of signals in the array. So I want to perform PSD and CSD on it like.
CSD: x[0] with x[1] .... x[0] with x[67] and following...
     x[1] with x[1] .... x[1] with x[67] and so on

But somehow the calculated values are way of my expectations and using them in further calculations leads to disturbing results.
Can anyone find my mistake? I am completely lost atm. Can't see the tree for the forest.

```
x = np.load('/home/daniel/Dropbox/[...]')

nfft = 512
n_freqs = nfft/2+1
n_epochs = len(x) # in this case there are 68 channels, does not want to change the variable name
sfreq = 1000

def compute_mean_psd_csd(x, n_epochs, nfft, sfreq):
    '''Computes mean of PSD and CSD for signals.'''

    Rxy = np.zeros((n_epochs, n_epochs, n_freqs), dtype=complex)
    Rxx = np.zeros((n_epochs, n_epochs, n_freqs), dtype=complex)
    Ryy = np.zeros((n_epochs, n_epochs, n_freqs), dtype=complex)
    for i in range(n_epochs):
        for j in range(n_epochs):
            Rxy[i,j], freqs = mlab.csd(x[i], x[j], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
            Rxx[i,j], _____ = mlab.psd(x[i], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
            Ryy[i,j], _____ = mlab.psd(x[i], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
```

Comment: It's been years since I touched matlab, but I think you are better off trying the code in Matlab directly (or at least make a version of it if you don't own one) and debug there. If you don't succeed ask a different question with the Matlab tag (will increase chances for you to get an answer)

Comment: It is just a module and for my further program it is necessary to keep it in python code. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Just saying that because it is "the same code as Matlab" you will have a better chance getting an answer in the Matlab domain (and many Matlab users aren't veteran coders that can "read python" and transform it in their head). After you find the bug, fix the python ofcourse